# GraphQLAuthorize attribute not firing [graphql]

Tags: graphql

I am working on the qraphQL api and I am trying to use authorization attribute  GraphQLAuthorize in GraphQL.Server.Authorization.AspNetCore; I have created policy in startup.cd configureService but not recognized by GraphQLAuthorize attribute.

The  [GraphQLAuthorize(Policy = "AUTHORIZED")] is not working.
while the AuthorizeWith("AUTHORIZED") is working

```
using GraphQL.Repository.GraphQL.Types;
using GraphQL.Repository.Repositories;
using GraphQL.Types;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GraphQL.Server.Authorization.AspNetCore;

namespace GraphQL.Repository.GraphQL
{
    [GraphQLAuthorize(Policy = "AUTHORIZED")]
    public class MenuQuery : ObjectGraphType
    {
        public MenuQuery(MenuRepository menuRepository)
        {
            Field<ListGraphType<NavigationMenuType>>(
                "NavigationMenu",
                arguments: new QueryArguments(new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<IdGraphType>> { Name = "applicationId" }),
                resolve: context =>
                {
                    var user = (ClaimsPrincipal)context.UserContext;

                    var applicationId = context.GetArgument<int>("applicationId");
                    return menuRepository.GetNavigationMenus(applicationId);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

//startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
//using GraphQL;
using GraphQL.Server;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using GraphQL.Repository.Entities;
using GraphQL.Repository.Repositories;
using GraphQL.Repository.GraphQL;
using GraphQL.Repository.GraphQL.Types;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
using GraphQL.Server.Ui.GraphiQL;
using GraphQL.Server.Ui.Playground;

namespace GraphQL.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<MenuManagementDevContext>(options =>
              options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:CarvedRockContext"]));

            services.AddScoped<MenuRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<MenuQuery>();

            services.AddScoped<NavigationMenuType>();
            services.AddScoped<RoleNavigationMenuType>();
            services.AddScoped<RoleType>();

            services.AddScoped<IDependencyResolver>(s => new FuncDependencyResolver(s.GetRequiredService));
            services.AddScoped<MenuSchema>();

            services.AddGraphQL(o => { o.ExposeExceptions = true; })
                .AddGraphQLAuthorization(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("AUTHORIZED", p => p.RequireAuthenticatedUser());
                })
                .AddGraphTypes(ServiceLifetime.Scoped).AddUserContextBuilder(httpContext => httpContext.User)
                .AddDataLoader()
                .AddWebSockets();

            services.AddCors();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseCors(builder =>
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());

            app.UseWebSockets();
            app.UseGraphQLWebSockets<MenuSchema>("/graphql");
            app.UseGraphQL<MenuSchema>();
            app.UseGraphiQLServer(new GraphiQLOptions());
            app.UseGraphQLPlayground(new GraphQLPlaygroundOptions());


        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Were you able to solve this?